# err_too_many_redirects in nginx subdomain config

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

I was trying to config my subdomain [www.chat.feromonn.com](http://www.chat.feromonn.com) but in browser its giving message "too many redirect"

Please let me know what i am making mistake :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name chat.feromonn.com www.chat.feromonn.com;
  return 301 https://www.chat.feromonn.com$request_uri;
}

server {
 listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
 listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

 server_name www.chat.feromonn.com chat.feromonn.com;
 root /home/feromonn/htdocs/www.chat.feromonn.com/public;

    # Your configuration for chat.feromonn.com goes here.

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/chat.feromonn.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/chat.feromonn.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


   access_log /home/feromonn/logs/nginx/access.log main;
   error_log /home/feromonn/logs/nginx/error.log;

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://85.31.235.65;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
    proxy_redirect http://85.31.235.65 http://www.chat.feromonn.com;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout      720;
    proxy_send_timeout         720;
    proxy_read_timeout         720;
    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}

  location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf|map)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
  }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
break;
  }
}


server {
    if ($host = chat.feromonn.com) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: 1) You didn't look any further than the main screen of your browser; the web developer tools are just a click away 2) you didn't check the log files on your server 3) the check for scheme on the :443 server is, at best redundant, 4) you are using permanent redirects when the config is not finalized 5) the third server block should not be there